# Chebyshev's inequality/ problem

Tags: probability

A random variable $X$ with $\mu=3$ and $\sigma^2=2$. Use the Chebyshev's inequality to obtain a superior limit for $P(|X-3|\geq 2)$ and $P(|X-3|\geq 1)$.

So for the first one i did this:

$P(|X-3|\geq 2)\leq \frac{2}{4} \Rightarrow P(|X-3|\geq 2)\leq \frac{1}{2}$ But the answer in the book is 1.
And for the second one:
$P(|X-3|\geq 1 )\leq \frac{2}{1}\Rightarrow P(|X-3|\geq 1 )\leq 2$ But again the answer in the book is $\frac{1}{4}$

Am i doing something wrong?

Comment: Are you sure your book doesn't have $\sigma =2$ rather than $\sigma^2=2$? (If not maybe that's a mistake *they* made).

Comment: And it's inconsistent to have $P(|X-3| \ge 2) > P(|X-3|\ge 1)$ did you mean $4$ rather than $1/4$ ?

Comment: @spaceisdarkgreen but if $\sigma =2$ then in the second one it would be 4 instead $\frac{1}{4}$

Comment: Yes but as I said in my second comment $1/4$ would be inconsistent. The second answer must be larger than the first one (as it is in your answers). Sometimes books are hopelessly riddled with typos. In answer to your main question, yes, you are using chebyshev right.